# Conda, Django, Gunicorn and Supervisor bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: deployment, django, supervisord, gunicorn, anaconda

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L5vhIyQFQk) to deploy my Django app, but modified my executable `/var/www/my_django_project/bin/gunicorn_start` to use my conda env instead of virtualenv.

```
CONDA_SRC=/home/justin/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
GUNICORN=/home/justin/anaconda3/pkgs/gunicorn-20.0.4-py38_0/bin/gunicorn
...
source $CONDA_SRC
conda activate myenv
```

When executing `sudo bin/gunicorn_start`, I got:

```
“starting backend”
bin/gunicorn_start: /home/justin/anaconda3/pkgs/gunicorn-20.0.4-py38_0/bin/gunicorn: /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
bin/gunicorn_start: line 25: /home/justin/anaconda3/pkgs/gunicorn-20.0.4-py38_0/bin/gunicorn: Success
```

and my supervisor.log shows:

```
supervisor: couldn't exec /var/www/my_django_project/bin/gunicorn_start: EACCES
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

Comment: Why are you using supervisord?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the base of my `GUNICORN` path to the directory containing my conda environment binaries. This can be found with `which python` while your conda env is activated, which gives: `/home/justin/anaconda3/envs/production/bin/python`. Use `/home/justin/anaconda3/envs/production/bin/gunicorn`.

`bin/gunicorn_start` executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=”backend”
DJANGODIR=/var/www/my_django_project/backend
SOCKFILE=/var/www/my_django_project/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=django
GROUP=my_django_project
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=backend.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=backend.wsgi
CONDA_SRC=/home/justin/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
GUNICORN=/home/justin/anaconda3/envs/production/bin/gunicorn

echo “starting backend”

cd $DJANGODIR
    source $CONDA_SRC
conda activate myenv
    export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH
    
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec $GUNICORN
 ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

My supervisor config was also missing `sh` in the `command` argument and my supervisor config used the wrong extension. Make sure the extension is `.conf`. Heres' my updated `django.conf`:

```
[program:django]
command =sh /var/www/my_django_project/bin/gunicorn_start
user = django
stdout_logfile = /var/www/my_django_project/backend/logs/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Hope this helps anyone else having this issue.